# How to do deep copy of Excel range values in Office-JS?

Tags: javascript, office-js

It seems that the Excel JS-API does shallow copies of Range.values. If I want to read a range from one place and write differently modified copies of it to 2 different places I need to use a deep copy of the range: how do I do that?
This code still does a shallow copy:

```
async function setValue() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            // A1 contains 9876543210
            let rng1 = sheet.getRange("a1").load("values");
            await context.sync();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rng1.values));
            // rng1 value is correct =9876543210
            let rng2 = sheet.getRange("B4");
            let rng3 = sheet.getRange("B6");
            let avar = [[]];
            for (var j = 0; j < rng1.values.length; j++) {
                for (var k = 0; k < rng1.values[0].length; k++) {
                    avar[j][k] = rng1.values[j][k];
                }
            }
            rng3.values = avar;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(avar));
            // rng2 value is correct =9876543210
            let avar2 = avar[0][0];
            rng3.values[0][0] =avar2 + 0.01;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rng3.values));
            //  rng3 value is correct =9876543210.01
            rng2.values = avar;
            console.log("Show values of the 3  ranges before Sync")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rng1.values));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rng2.values));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rng3.values));
            // rng2 and rng3 both show as 987654321.01
            // BUT ONLY Rng3 has been altered!
            await context.sync();
        });

        console.log("Done!");
    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - you can make a deep copy using JQuery extend

```
    let avar = [];
     $.extend(true, avar, rng1.values);
    rng3.values = avar;
```